# Error while trying to call variable from another file in js

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am using a page object model. So each page.js file contains a variable `url` and 'AddButtonId'. I call the function to launch the page by passing the pageName and elementID.

page.js

```
module.exports = {
    e: {
        url: 'http://localhost:4200/',
        AddButtonId: 'addButton',

},
};
```

function definition:

```
urlCall: function (pageName) {
          return  browser.get(pageName+".e.url");
        },

clickButton: function(pageName,elementID){
             var x = pageName+".e."+elementID;
             element(by.id(x)).click();
            },
```

here I pass pageName and ID while calling the function.

```
    urlcall(page);

    clickButton(page, AddButtonId);
```

But instead of getting the variable value (http://localhost:4200/) from the page object file, the browser.get() tries to load "pageName.e.url". 
Instead of passing "addButton" in "clickButton" function, it passes "page.e.AddButtonId" and fails with the error " NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="page.e.AddButtonId"])"

Comment: Try changing `pageName+".e.url"` to `pageName.e.url`

Comment: I am passing pageName in the function. I need to concatinate "pageName" and ".e.url", so that I can call the variable.

Comment: Did you mean concatenate `pageName` and `e.url` rather than `".e.url"`

Comment: pageName.e.url is the varible I want to call. I pass the pageName as parameter in the function. Then I need to concatinate "pageName" and ".e.url"

Comment: So `pageName` is passed in to the function and it has a property `e`, and `e` has a property called `url`?

Comment: Please show page.js.

Comment: added the page.js above.. but my issue is not the path. my issue is that browser .get() loads "pageName.e/url" as sting in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to import the page object by using the passed-in pageName to get the import file path.

// pageA.js

```
module.exports = {
    e: {
        url: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    },
    ...
};
```

// function: urlCall

```
urlCall: function (pageName) {
  // you need to import the page object.
  var page = require(pageName+'.js');
  var x = page.e.url;
  browser.get(x);
},
```

// function clickButton

```
clickButton: function(pageName,elementID){
    var page = require(pageName+'.js');
    var x = page.e[elementID];
    element(by.id(x)).click();
},
```

// test.js

```
urlCall('pageA')
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for "urlCall" function. But i faced similar issue while passing pageName and variableName in another function. I have updated the description. please have a look at the "clickButton" function and suggest a solution

Comment: Update the code for `clickButton` in answer. Anyway your code implement/design is not a good pattern.

Comment: Thanks. The implement/design is so because I am using Cucumber-PageObjectModel combination. I am writing Tests in Gherkin which would have the pageName and elementID. The step definitions for the same will call the functions. So I am writing reusable steps where anyone can pass pageName and elementID to perform functions on any page

Comment: Can anyone give me a java equivalent to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript resolves your expression to a string. Instead, you need to use square brackets like pageName["e"]["url"] or proper property access: pageName.e.url